# Does Paypal iOS SDK support parallel payments?

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am new to PayPal.Can i know that how to use paypal adaptive for parallel payment.Please guided me how to do that functionality.

Thanks in-advance
honey

Answer (score 0):

PayPal iOS SDK doesn't currently support chained or parallel payments.
To incorporate these features into your mobile apps see the [MPL](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL) on GitHub and [MPL](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/) documentation